# MySQL/MariaDB - After insert, delete row that matches specified conditions trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, mariadb

I have an audit table that stores information related to an intermediary table used for an ETL process. I have a trigger in the parent table that stores actions about what was performed on a particular row in the audit table.

```
CREATE TABLE `audit_table` (
  `RowID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `apptid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `modified` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `data_push_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RowID`,`apptid`,`type`,`data_push_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

- RowID - PK from the parent table; this PK value in the primary table
  is `AUTO_INCREMENT`
- apptid - PK in parent table
- modified - Unix timestamp of when the
  row was last modified
- type - The action that was performed; can be
  'Insert' or 'Delete'
- data_push_id - Refers to column in parent
  table that contains the    batch id of when the data was last
  upserted into the parent table. So    data_push_id 1 can refer to a
  certain set of records in the parent    table, data_push_id 2 can
  refer to another set of records, and so on.

What I want to do is this:

- After insertion of a "delete" entry into the audit table...
- If there is an "insert" entry that has that same row number...
- Insert the "delete" row...
- And, immediately afterwards, delete both the "insert" and "delete" rows for that row number.

This is my initial attempt but it returns an error:

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS `test` AFTER Insert ON 
        `audit_table` FOR EACH ROW
        IF (OLD.`rowid` = NEW.`rowid` AND NEW.`type` = 'Delete' AND OLD.`type` = 'Insert')
        DELETE FROM `audit_table` duap_audit WHERE duap_audit.rowid = OLD.rowid 

SQL Error [1363] [HY000]: (conn=18464) There is no OLD row in on INSERT trigger
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Only an BEFORE or AFTER UPDATE OR DELTE TRIGGER has a OLD row

INSERT TRIGGER only have a NEW row, which is clear, they have no old values to replace

> In an INSERT trigger, only NEW.col_name can be used; there is no old row. In a DELETE trigger, only OLD.col_name can be used; there is no new row. In an UPDATE trigger, you can use OLD.col_name to refer to the columns of a row before it is updated and NEW.col_name to refer to the columns of the row after it is updated.

[see manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)